# Angular 9 routing based on first character of string

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my Angular 9 app I'd like to navigate to a certain page when the path begins with "@".

For example "mywebsite.com/@sample-user" should be navigated to User component,  "mywebsite.com/@sample-user/:post-id" to UserPostView component and "mywebsite.com/sample-user" (no @ at the beginning of path) should be navigated to a different component.

```
const routes: Routes = [{path: '@:username', component: UserComponent}, {path: '@:username/:pist-id', component: UserPostViewComponent}, {path: 'sample-user', component: InternalComponent}]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a custom matcher with regex for this.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
 {
    matcher: (url) => {
      if (url.length === 1 && url[0].path.match(/^@[\w]+$/gm)) {
        return {
          consumed: url,
          posParams: {
            username: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.substr(1), {})
          }
        };
      }
      return null;
    },
    component: ProfileComponent
 }
])
```

Check this article out it has all the answers.

https://medium.com/@brandontroberts/custom-route-matching-with-the-angular-router-fbdd48665483